# How to get each value with list comprehension inside other list?

Tags: python, list, for-loop, list-comprehension

Need help with this **list comprehension**...

Here is my code:

```
w1_comb_l1=[n1, pos_pred_list[0], [i for i in pos_days_w1]]
```

That **comprehension** gives this output: `[209, 49684, [9351, 9346, 8103, 7676, 8739, 3925, 2544]]`.

I need help getting those values that are in inner brackets out, therefore, here is desired output: `[209, 49684, 9351, 9346, 8103, 7676, 8739, 3925, 2544]` - without inner list

It is probably a small fix.

Comment: In this particular case `[n1, pos_pred_list[0], *pos_days_w1]` should be enough.

Comment: @Austin I tried `w1_comb_l1=[n1, pos_pred_list[0], lambda l: [item for pos_days_w1 in l for item in pos_days_w1]]` it gives me **[209, 49684, <function __main__.<lambda>(l)>]**, as you can see i'm storing the function in this case...

Comment: @bereal It does work! Any chance you could shine some light for me on how `*pos_days_w1` works or point to right reading? Thank you.

Comment: You can do `[y for x in w1_comb_l1 for y in x]`. But this is after creation of `w1_comb_l1`, which you can avoid using the trick from @bereal.

Comment: @DGomonov this is a feature called [unpacking](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.5.html#whatsnew-pep-448), in this generalized form it was introduced in Python 3.5.

Comment: `w1_comb_l1=[n1, pos_pred_list[0],*pos_days_w1]`